# Multi-Step time series LSTM Network in pytorch

Tags: lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am having issues with the LSTM function in pytorch. I am using an LSTM neural network to forecast a certain value. The input is multidimensional (multiple features) and the output should be one dimensional (only one feature that needs to be forecasted). I want to forecast something 1-6 timesteps in advance. I want to use multi timestep input as well. Now I have to different ways of achieving this but neither of them seem to work.

The first one is making 6 different many-to-one networks each forecasting another timestep 1-6h in advance, but still using the recurrent structure (see picture) when forecasting multiple time steps ahead (so not just shifting the target data by 1-6 hours). Another option would be a many to many neural network, this would work fine as well I think. (also see picture)

My input now looks like: where first the different parameters at the same timestep are grouped and then further each time all the timesteps we want to use in the forecast are grouped (look back)

```
tensor([[[-0.2800, -0.6381, -0.1033, -0.4941,  0.0016],
         [-0.3159,  0.1378, -0.1010, -0.4529,  0.0016],
         [-0.2800,  0.1378, -0.0963, -0.4706,  0.1150],
         ...,
         [-0.5673, -0.2149, -0.0598, -0.4000,  0.2850],
         [-0.3518, -0.4265, -0.0669, -0.3646,  0.3417],
         [-0.2440, -0.0738, -0.0657, -0.3823,  0.2283]],

        [[-0.3159,  0.1378, -0.1010, -0.4529,  0.0016],
         [-0.2800,  0.1378, -0.0963, -0.4706,  0.1150],
         [-0.7469,  0.1731, -0.0845, -0.4176,  0.3417],
         ...,
         [-0.3518, -0.4265, -0.0669, -0.3646,  0.3417],
         [-0.2440, -0.0738, -0.0657, -0.3823,  0.2283],
         [-0.1722, -0.5323, -0.0610, -0.4117,  0.2283]],

        [[-0.2800,  0.1378, -0.0963, -0.4706,  0.1150],
         [-0.7469,  0.1731, -0.0845, -0.4176,  0.3417],
         [-0.7829, -0.4265, -0.0692, -0.4176,  0.4550],
         ...,
         [-0.2440, -0.0738, -0.0657, -0.3823,  0.2283],
         [-0.1722, -0.5323, -0.0610, -0.4117,  0.2283],
         [-0.1363, -0.8850, -0.0669, -0.4294,  0.1150]],

        ...,

        [[-0.3518,  0.2083, -0.1386,  0.8479, -0.1684],
         [-0.3518,  0.4552, -0.1398,  0.9480,  0.0016],
         [-0.2800, -0.4265, -0.1398,  0.9126,  0.0583],
         ...,
         [-1.0343, -0.1443, -0.1433,  0.8479,  0.0016],
         [-0.8906,  0.3847, -0.1445,  1.0304, -0.2251],
         [-0.7829, -0.0385, -0.1433,  1.0127, -0.1117]],

        [[-0.3518,  0.4552, -0.1398,  0.9480,  0.0016],
         [-0.2800, -0.4265, -0.1398,  0.9126,  0.0583],
         [-0.4596, -0.9202, -0.1410,  0.8479,  0.1150],
         ...,
         [-0.8906,  0.3847, -0.1445,  1.0304, -0.2251],
         [-0.7829, -0.0385, -0.1433,  1.0127, -0.1117],
         [-0.8547,  0.2436, -0.1422,  0.9715, -0.0550]],

        [[-0.2800, -0.4265, -0.1398,  0.9126,  0.0583],
         [-0.4596, -0.9202, -0.1410,  0.8479,  0.1150],
         [-0.6392, -0.5323, -0.1422,  0.8655,  0.0016],
         ...,
         [-0.7829, -0.0385, -0.1433,  1.0127, -0.1117],
         [-0.8547,  0.2436, -0.1422,  0.9715, -0.0550],
         [-0.9984, -0.0033, -0.1422,  0.8597,  0.0583]]])
```

And the output looks like, where the different timesteps 1-6h in advance are grouped.  I can change this easily.

```
tensor([[[ -7.],
         [ -9.],
         [-11.],
         [-13.],
         [-13.]],

        [[ -9.],
         [-11.],
         [-13.],
         [-13.],
         [-10.]],

        [[-11.],
         [-13.],
         [-13.],
         [-10.],
         [ -9.]],

        ...,

        [[-12.],
         [-10.],
         [-10.],
         [-10.],
         [ -9.]],

        [[-10.],
         [-10.],
         [-10.],
         [ -9.],
         [ -8.]],

        [[-10.],
         [-10.],
         [ -9.],
         [ -8.],
         [-10.]]])
```

Now I have no idea how to use the LSTM structure to do multi timesteps forecasting. The output layer should be linear.

The batch size does not really matter to me, I think it can be one for now.